# Flutter get user Id on another page and convert it in a String ("type 'Future<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'String'")

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, userid

i need to get the User id from a current log in user on my profile Page. I have followed the net ninja tutorial on Youtube. This is my current way

```
 final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
getCurrentUser() async {
    final FirebaseUser user = await _auth.currentUser();
    final uid = user.uid;
    // Similarly we can get email as well
    //final uemail = user.email;
    print(uid);
    //print(uemail);
  }
```

But if i call this in my Scaffold i get this output

> type 'Future' is not a subtype of type 'String'

And the Uid. How can i convert this to a String? Or is there a more more elegant way?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You could try putting it inside a `FutureBuilder`

```dart
FutureBuilder<String>(
  future: () async {
    FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
    FirebaseUser user = await auth.currentUser();
    String uid = user.uid.toString();
    return uid;
  }(),
  builder: (context, snapshot) {
    if (snapshot.hasData) {
      return Text(snapshot.data);           // <- Customize your widget here
    } else {
      return CircularProgressIndicator();
    }
  },
)
```